# Change appearance of toolbar from a UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, toolbar

I did add a toolbar to my UINavigationController and that works as it should. But I don't see any possibility to change the appearance(like other backgroundcolor etc.) of the toolbar.

The [docs](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/toolbar) shows me that an UINavigationController has a toolbar property but it is readonly.

Do I have to do an custom UIView or is there any other given way?

cheers
cyril

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While the toolbar property itself may be readonly, it's properties are as they are normally.

The toolbar being readonly means that you can't set a different instance of a toolbar for that property. The toolbars properties, such as it's `barStyle` are readwrite and are modifiable.

Simply call:

```
myNavController.toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque; // exchange this style constant for whatever you want to use.
```

Comment: ahhh right. just read readonly and didn't think of it.

thx a lot